# How can I output a boolean variable as "yes/no" in VueJS 0.11?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a field called is_admin. I am using VueJS to build a autocompleting search of all of the users.

I want to output the is_admin field as either true/false or yes/no, but my database field is boolean, 1 or 0.

How can I output the value in a readable way instead of as the boolean field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<span>{{ user.is_admin ? "Admin" : "User" }}</span>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you need to do this more than once, you might consider putting the logic in a filter:

```
Vue.filter('yesno', function (value) {
  return value ? 'Yes' : 'No';
})
```

and then use it like this:

```
<div>
  Admin? {{ is_admin | yesno }}
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and DRY, love it!

Comment: beautiful. this can also be written as `Vue.filter('yesno', value => (value ? 'Yes' : 'No'));` in es6 syntax